# link between footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

How can I link a footnote in another footnote?

for example I have this footnote`\footnote{Some book of an author}` in a certain page (let say footnote number 3 page 5). I want to write a link in another footnote that automatically say the number of the previous footnote and the page. For example `\footnote{(cfr Nota 3, p.5)}`but "Nota 3, p.5" has to be written automatically, and the second footnote has to be clickable in my pdf file and it should take the user to the first footnote.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual `label{…}` inside a footnote and then refer back to the footnote with `\ref{…}`to print the number of the footnote. Together with the `hyperref`package you can make the links clickable. The page number can be accessed using `\pageref`. This would be the most simple way of achieving the desired result, even though you have to type “Nota” and “p.” by hand.

**MWE for this solution**

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Text\footnote{This is the first footnote.\label{footnote1}}
    Text\footnote{This refers to Nota \ref{footnote1}, p.\pageref{footnote1}.} 
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** As promised, here is a way to automatically print the name for footnote (with `cleveref`) and page and omit the page reference, if both footnotes are on the same page (with `varioref`).

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{varioref}
    \usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    Text\footnote{This is the first footnote.\label{footnote1}}
    \newpage
    \newpage
    Text\footnote{This is the second footnote. It refers to \vref{footnote1}.} 
\end{document}
```

This almost gets you there. There is still some customization needed in order to print “p. X” instead of “a pagina X”, but I have to go now :-)

Comment: See also `\vref{<label>}` from the `varioref` package to use "smart" references (e.g. "See *on previous page*" instead of "See on page 5" if the text is written on page 6)